# Showing `Missing permission` even after adding permission inside manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions

Here is the warning
[image]

Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have tried by removing space from permission, by restarting android studio, by invalidate and restart, by clean > rebuild. Nothing worked. Comment for more info.

Comment: Is that lint error code from a submodule, and the Manifest where you added the permission in a parent module, or root project? If so include the permission in a/the submodule manifest where the code exists.

Comment: How do I add permission in submodule manifest?

Comment: Same way you would in any android app/library module ..

Comment: Can you please tell the path?

Comment: Same problem is occurring inside activity which is in root folder(com/example/app_name)

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with `HIDE_OVERLAY_WINDOWS` permission in Android Studio 2021.2.1